# isAnnotationPresent vs getDeclaredAnnotation != null

Tags: java, performance, annotations

Looking at the `isAnnotationPresent` method found in the `Method` class, all what it does is invoke `getDeclaredAnnotation` using it's parameters and checking the nullity of it.

If I use `isAnnotationPresent(...)` instead of `getDeclaredAnnotation(...) != null` to verify the presence of an annotation, does it affect performance?

Comment: Not in any way that you'll ever notice. Use the method that best described what you're trying to do, which in this case is to call `isAnnotationPresent()`. I've downvoted, because you could have tested this for yourself, aka done some **research**, but you really shouldn't. [Beware premature optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/80084/202153).

Answer (score 0):

You should always use the method doing what you need, i.e., here `isAnnotationPresent`. It's obviously better for readability and it may sometimes be even better for speed.

Without looking at the code, what is the most straightforward implementation? Obviously, testing `getDeclaredAnnotation(...) != null`. So what can you lose? One method call. Method calls are costly, but wherever it matters, they get inlined, so they're basically free. You just can't lose.

In this case, you most probably can't win either, and if you could, it'd by by a tiny hard to measure amount only.

But imagine a similar case for collections: `isEmpty()` vs. `size() == 0`. The latter can be much more costly for some fancy collections, e.g., some funny linked list or a collection backed by a database. Indeed, `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` is oftentimes slower than `IF EXISTS(...)`.

So always go for the simpler / more readable solution. Performance-wise it usually doesn't matter and when it does, you'll probably gain.

The only optimizations worth doing upfront are such concerning algorithmic complexity (e.g., you surely don't want to do bubble-sort).